# How to put image and text on same line in a GitHub README.md?

Tags: github, markdown

I would like to display the image and text on same line. This is what I have currently:

[image]

```
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/84743905/174507937-c8637dd7-5a10-4c12-bf23-945c7872ace2.png) <h3>TECHNOLOGIES</h3>
```

Comment: Put the image inside the `h3`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I did try to put it in h3 but the image was not displaying and just showing the markdown.

Comment: Because you're mixing HTML and Markdown. Either use HTML or Markdown for both elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick. You'll just need to edit the height value to your liking

```
<h3><img align="center" height="30" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/84743905/174507937-c8637dd7-5a10-4c12-bf23-945c7872ace2.png"> TECHNOLOGIES</h3>
```